# How do I make the format match my time data?

Tags: python, datetime

I would like to make some graphs with a dataframe that I read in to python as a `.csv` file.  The dates are in the format `1-Jan` but when I try to convert the datetime using the following line:

```
metdata['Date']=metdata['Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x), format='%d-%MMM'))
```

It throws this error:

> ValueError: time data '1-Jan' does not match format '%d-%MMM' (match)

I can't figure out why the data doesn't match the format. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

proper format for 3 letters month in pandas is `%b`, therefore

```
metdata['Date']=metdata['Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x), format='%d-%b'))
```

if you don't have the year, it will be added automatically as 1900

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` uses the same string formatting as `datetime` (which uses the C's `strftime`). You can read about it more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Formatting directives don't have multiple letters after the `%`.  I think you want `%d-%b`

```
In [52]: datetime.datetime.strptime('1-Jan', '%d-%MMM')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-946e04d8e511> in <module>()
----> 1 datetime.datetime.strptime('1-Jan', '%d-%MMM')

C:\Users\colinc719\Miniconda2\lib\_strptime.pyc in _strptime(data_string, format)
    330     if not found:
    331         raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
--> 332                          (data_string, format))
    333     if len(data_string) != found.end():
    334         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %

ValueError: time data '1-Jan' does not match format '%d-%MMM'

In [53]: datetime.datetime.strptime('1-Jan', '%d-%b')
Out[53]: datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: This changed the error to:

ValueError: day is out of range for month

which I'm assuming is because the %d calls for a "zero-padded decimal number" according to the link you attached.  I guess I need to convert the dates into two-digit numbers?

Comment: What is the string that causes it to fail?

Comment: Ahhhh it was the leap day being in the incorrect year.  Very sharp, python.  Thanks for your help!